# HAVING clause and performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I've got a performance problem with a SQL (MySql) query. Basically I have a table similar to this:

```
ID   PRICE    ID  OBJECT
-----------------------------
1    500.00   1   1
2    300.00   1   1
3    400.00   1   1
4    100.00   1   1
5    100.00   1   1
6    100.00   2   3
```

And I need to get the maximum amount of lines given an amount.

For example, given the amount 1000.00 the query must returns these ids (order by price asc) and the total price.

```
ID  PRICE TOTAL_PRICE
---------------------------------
4   100   100.00
5   100   200.00
2   300   500.00
3   400   900.00
```

Atm I'm using a query similar to the below one:

```
set @total=0; 
select a.id, a.price , @total:=@total + a.price as total_price , a.id_user 
from shares a 
where a.`id_user` != 0 and a.id_object = 1 
having @total < 1000.00  order by a.price asc;
```

It works fine but it's not efficient. It takes around 1.5 seconds to extract the data (the table has around 1M lines).

The problem is related to the Having clause.

Do you have any suggestions?

Is there a way to perform this type of query **without** using the clause **Having** ?

Comment: why don't you include it in the `where` clause?

Comment: `having` clause is only used with `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this (`cumulative sum`) is what you are looking for:

```
set @total = 0;

SELECT ID,
       Price,
       Total_Price
FROM (
    SELECT a.*
        ,(@total := @total + price) AS total_price
    FROM shares a
    WHERE a.id_user != 0
        AND a.id_object = 1
    ORDER BY a.price
    ) q1
WHERE q1.total_price < 1000;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4311/24/1)

Comment: unfortunately that query doesn't resolve the performance issue that I'm having.  Note that _having_ clause works without _group by_ http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57445/use-of-having-without-group-by-in-sql-queries